# iOS : Swift : Right and Left view controller transitions between mutiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, catransition

I have close to 8 view controllers , Each and every view controller has next and back button . How could I do left and right transitions here through swift code . To be more specific on tapping back , previous view controller should slide from left and on tapping next , the next view controller should slide from right.

I am pretty new to iOS development , Any help would be really appreciable.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: That is what `UIPageViewController` is designed for: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller

Comment: @SrAn did you achive what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using [`UIPageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) combining it with its delegate.

However, I'm gonna shamelessly point you to my open source project of custom container with interactive transitions - [InteractiveTransitioningContainer](https://github.com/MilanNosal/InteractiveTransitioningContainer). While it aims at allowing to implement an interactive container (as an example it includes a container that allows swiping through viewControllers the way as `UIPageViewController` works), you can use the `SwipeToSlideInteractiveTransitioningContainer` class to achieve what you want:

```
// here you will want your 8 controllers
let vcs = [FirstViewController(), SecondViewController(), ThirdViewController()]

let container = SwipeToSlideInteractiveTransitioningContainer(with: vcs)
// this will disable swiping to navigate between containees
container.interactive = false
self.present(container, animated: true, completion: nil)

// shows the second viewController (index based from 0)
container.show(at: 1, animated: true)

// or move using previous and next convenience methods
let success = container.showNext(animated: true)
```

You can install it using Cocoa pods. Any feedback welcome :).

Comment: please use lazy for your vcs

Comment: @Fabio feel free to submit a pull request :)